# How to solve this integrals (delta Dirac)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, dirac-delta, wave-equation

i have the following problem :

$$\int_0^L\sum_{i=1}^{n=3} \delta\left(x-x_{i}\right) \cos(2\pi x/L ) \left\{ A_{1}'(t) \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi x}{L}\right) + B_{1}'(t) \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi x}{L}\right)\right\} dx $$

With $x_i={L/6,3L/6,5L/6}$.

basically, I did this:

---

$$= \int_0^L\sum_{i=1}^{n=3} \delta\left(x-x_{i}\right)\left\{ A_{1}'(t) \cos ^2\left(\frac{2 \pi x}{L}\right)+B_{1}'(t) \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi x}{L}\right)\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi x}{L}\right)\right\}dx $$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^{n=3}\left\{  A_{1}'(t) \cos ^2\left(\frac{2 \pi x_i}{L}\right)+B_{1}'(t) \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi x}{L}\right)\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi x_i}{L}\right)\right\} $$

$$= \frac{3}{2}A_1'(t)+\frac{3}{2}B_1'(t).$$

---

But this is far from what my teacher found, he basically found $3A_1'(t)$, anyone can help me or explain to me my mistake(s)? thanks!

Comment: sorry, the sum is from i=1 to n=3

Comment: from i=1 to n=3 ... that looks peculiar.

Comment: It seems to me pretty perverse to write $$\int_0^L \sum_{i=1}^3 \delta(x-x_i)f(x)\;dx\quad\text{instead of}\quad \sum_{i=1}^3 f(x_i)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is $\frac{3}{2}A_1'(t)$.

\begin{align*}
&\int_0^L \sum_{i=1}^3 \delta(x-x_i) \cos \left( \frac{2\pi x}{L} \right) \left( A_1'(t) \cos \left( \frac{2\pi x}{L} \right) + B_1'(t) \sin \left( \frac{2\pi x}{L} \right)\right) \,\mathrm{d}x  \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^3 \int_0^L \delta(x-x_i) \cos \left( \frac{2\pi x}{L} \right) \left( A_1'(t) \cos \left( \frac{2\pi x}{L} \right) + B_1'(t) \sin \left( \frac{2\pi x}{L} \right)\right) \,\mathrm{d}x  \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^3 \cos \left( \frac{2\pi x_i}{L} \right) \left( A_1'(t) \cos \left( \frac{2\pi x_i}{L} \right) + B_1'(t) \sin \left( \frac{2\pi x_i}{L} \right)\right) \Theta(L-x_i)  \\
&= \cos \left( \frac{2\pi x_1}{L} \right) \left( A_1'(t) \cos \left( \frac{2\pi x_1}{L} \right) + B_1'(t) \sin \left( \frac{2\pi x_1}{L} \right)\right) \Theta(L-x_1)
\\ & \qquad + \cos \left( \frac{2\pi x_2}{L} \right) \left( A_1'(t) \cos \left( \frac{2\pi x_2}{L} \right) + B_1'(t) \sin \left( \frac{2\pi x_2}{L} \right)\right) \Theta(L-x_2)
\\ & \qquad + \cos \left( \frac{2\pi x_3}{L} \right) \left( A_1'(t) \cos \left( \frac{2\pi x_3}{L} \right) + B_1'(t) \sin \left( \frac{2\pi x_3}{L} \right)\right) \Theta(L-x_3)  \\
&= 
\cos \left( \frac{2\pi \frac{L}{6}}{L} \right) \left( A_1'(t) \cos \left( \frac{2\pi \frac{L}{6}}{L} \right) + B_1'(t) \sin \left( \frac{2\pi \frac{L}{6}}{L} \right)\right) \Theta(L-\frac{L}{6})
\\ & \qquad + \cos \left( \frac{2\pi \frac{3L}{6}}{L} \right) \left( A_1'(t) \cos \left( \frac{2\pi \frac{3L}{6}}{L} \right) + B_1'(t) \sin \left( \frac{2\pi \frac{3L}{6}}{L} \right)\right) \Theta(L-\frac{3L}{6})
\\ & \qquad + \cos \left( \frac{2\pi \frac{5L}{6}}{L} \right) \left( A_1'(t) \cos \left( \frac{2\pi \frac{5L}{6}}{L} \right) + B_1'(t) \sin \left( \frac{2\pi \frac{5L}{6}}{L} \right)\right) \Theta(L-\frac{5L}{6})  \\
&= 
\cos \left( \frac{\pi}{3} \right) \left( A_1'(t) \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{3} \right) + B_1'(t) \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{3} \right)\right) \cdot 1
\\ & \qquad + \cos \left( \pi \right) \left( A_1'(t) \cos \left( \pi \right) + B_1'(t) \sin \left( \pi \right)\right) \cdot 1
\\ & \qquad + \cos \left( \frac{5\pi}{3} \right) \left( A_1'(t) \cos \left( \frac{5\pi}{3} \right) + B_1'(t) \sin \left( {5\pi}{3} \right)\right) \cdot 1  \\
&= 
\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{2} A_1'(t) + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} B_1'(t) \right)
\\ & \qquad + 
(-1) \left( -A_1'(t) + 0 B_1'(t) \right)
\\ & \qquad + 
\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{2} A_1'(t) + \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2} B_1'(t) \right)  \\
&= 
\frac{1}{4} A_1'(t) + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} B_1'(t)
+
A_1'(t) 
+
\frac{1}{4} A_1'(t) + \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{4} B_1'(t)  \\
&= \frac{3}{2} A_1'(t)  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks your sir